# how to access the SOAP request in the groovy script - SOAP UI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I am writing a groovy script to consume the SOAP web service. First i imported my 
WSDL in SOAP and created a project.

Then all the SOAP request are generated automatically.

Now am trying to write a groovy to call the SOAP service using the SOAP request generated.

[image]

Now here it is my groovy script

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


class Example {
   static void main(String[] args) {

String serviceInput="";
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://server:30280/so_ws/SO?WSDL");
post.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/soap+xml,application/dime,multipart/related,text/*");
post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "");

// access CreateNote SOAP request here to call PostMethod
   }
}
```

I want to access the same SOAP request generated in SOAP UI - CreateNote.
How can I access it?

My actuall requirement is to access all SOAP request in the groovy script - so that i can write one single script to test all the SOAP services in one go and that too in the sequence as per required

Comment: There is a first step which does the same right? why do you want to call it with groovy in the second step?

Comment: You just want the request? or you want to run the `CreateNote` test step from `CreateNoteScript` test step itself?

Comment: Ashish, have you got chance to look at the solution provided?

Comment: hello , yes this is rather use ful the approach u have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `Groovy Script` which gets the **request** from *its previous step of the same test case* like you have your test case currently.

**Script**

```
def req = context.testCase.getTestStepAt(context.currentStepIndex - 1).httpRequest.requestContent
log.info req
```

Comment: my aim is to test all the services in one groovy script , is it possible this way

Comment: can i use some kind of loop in it to access all the SOAP requests generated in SOAP UI

Comment: Of course, you can loop. But it all depends on how the test is designed and context is really needed. May be you want to create a new question with details?

Comment: here you go  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928383/how-to-access-all-soap-request-in-on-e-single-groovy-script